# CMake relative linking, executable fails to find shared libraries

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to learn CMake and for that purpose I am working with an example project of the structure shown below. I am trying to configure all the `CMakeLists.txt` files such that after `make install` I can copy the resulting `build` directory and copy-paste it around freely such that other people are able run the executable.

**Problem:** after running `make install` (maxOS 10.14.6 (Darwin 18.7.0)) everything works if I run the executable inside `build` BUT if I move the build directory from its original location - for example to Desktop - the executable is unable to find the shared libraries.  It seems that the reason for this is that the paths to the shared libraries are defined as absolute paths instead of relative paths with respect to the build directory.

**Question:** How can I build the project such that the executable finds the shared libs?

**Project structure:**

```
myapp
  |
  CMakeLists.txt (top-level)
  - build
  - app 
  |   CMakeLists.txt (app)
  |   - inc
  |       - app
  |          app.h  
  |   - src
  |      app.cpp
  |      main.cpp
  |    
  - external
      | 
      - mylib
          CMakeLists.txt (mylib)
          - inc
             - mylib
                mylib.h
          - src
             mylib.cpp
```

**CMakeLists:**

CMakeLists.txt (top-level)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(myapp)

add_subdirectory(external/mylib)
add_subdirectory(app)
```

CMakeLists.txt (app)

```
# myapp program

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(myapp_prog)

set(SOURCES ./src/)
set(HEADERS ./inc/app/)

set(SOURCE_FILES
        ${SOURCES}/app.cpp)

set(HEADER_FILES
        ${HEADERS}/app.h)


# All sources that need to be tested in unit test go into a static library
add_library(myapp_lib SHARED ${HEADER_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_include_directories(myapp_lib PUBLIC ${HEADERS})

# The main program
add_executable(prog ./src/main.cpp)
target_include_directories(prog PUBLIC ./inc/)

# Link the libraries
target_link_libraries(prog PRIVATE myapp_lib mylib)

install(TARGETS myapp_lib DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
```

CMakeLists.txt (mylib)

```
# mylib

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(mylib)

set(SOURCES src/)

set(HEADERS inc/mylib/)

set(SOURCE_FILES
     ${SOURCES}/mylib.cpp)

set(HEADER_FILES
    ${HEADERS}/mylib.h)

add_library(mylib SHARED ${HEADER_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC inc/)

install(TARGETS mylib DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
```

**C++ code:**

mylib.h

```
void mylib_print_hello();
```

mylib.cpp

```
#include "library.h"

#include <iostream>

void mylib_print_hello() {
    std::cout << "Hello from mylib!" << std::endl;
}
```

app.h

```
void myapp_hello();
```

app.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "app.h"

void myapp_hello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello from myapp!" << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "app/app.h"
#include "mylib/mylib.h"

int main()
{
    myapp_hello();
    mylib_print_hello();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you might be confusing the build step with the install step. By using ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}, you are passing an absolute path to your binary directory (build), which may interfere with the moving of the build afterwards. If you would like to ouput your libraries to a folder after the build, you may set the target of the library with:

```
set_target_property(<library-name> PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
```

This will affect only the build stage of your project. As far as installs go, you are better off using only relative paths in the install directives. These paths will be relative to your ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX} variable. For example, you would use:

```
install(TARGETS mylib DESTINATION lib)
```

To install the library under the ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib folder. Best practice states that you should **NEVER** manipulate this variable directly in your CMakeLists.txt files, as it could break a build somewhere down the line. Starting with CMake 3.15, it is possible to use cmake --install to install a project. This command allows setting an installation prefix, such as:

```
cmake --install . --prefix desired/install/path
```

With this, all your link path should stay valid.

Comment: If I use ```install(TARGETS mylib DESTINATION lib)``` the libraries are installed to ```/usr/local/lib/```which is not the behaviour I am seeking. I want all the libs and executables to be inside build such that build directory can be moved around without link paths getting broken.

Comment: How are you running the installation? From an IDE or command line? What command did you run?

Comment: standard command line 1) mkdir build 2) cd build 3) cmake .. 4) make install. I think the RPATH settings need to be configured.

Comment: 4) should be: cmake --install . --prefix desired/install/directory

Comment: I am afraid that 1) mkdir build 2) cd build 3) cmake .. 4) cmake --install . --prefix desired/install/directory does not build the executable

Comment: My bad, you may run cmake --build . --config Release right before the install to build.

Comment: Could you list the whole sequence of commands? Also, is this supposed to fix the relative paths?

Comment: This was not helpful and did not fix the issue.

Comment: Starting from a clean environment (no build folder.): 1) mkdir build ; 2) mkdir install ; 3) cd build ; 4) cmake .. ; 5) cmake --build . --config Release ; 6) cmake --install . --prefix ../install/ ; I do not know for mac, but consider that under windows, the dll must be in the same directory as the executable. This might be a restriction when moving a build around.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a `macos` tag to this question.

I think that you are looking for a relative [RPATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/MACOSX_RPATH.html). CMake builds the executable with an absolute `RPATH`, so if you move or rename the build directory the program stop working. In your example, you only need to modify the main program `CMakeLists.txt`, to change the value of the RPATHs that CMake inserts in your executable.

```
# The main program
add_executable(prog ./src/main.cpp)
target_include_directories(prog PUBLIC ./inc/)
set_target_properties(prog PROPERTIES BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE INSTALL_RPATH "@executable_path/;@executable_path/../external/mylib")
```

You can verify the values of the `LC_RPATH`s with this command from your build directory:

```
$ otool -l app/prog
```

For dependencies between libraries, it may also be useful "@loader_path" instead of @executable_path. And for other Unix operating systems, use "$ORIGIN". More information [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling).